# Setprecision doesn't work during exponentiation with base of 10 in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

My code should calculate with maximum precision different powers of different ints. Sometimes I have problem digits after nought point.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << setprecision(10000);
    int length = 5;
    long double Maxi = pow(10, length);
    cout << Maxi << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

prints

> 100000.00000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125

instead of

> 100000

Screen: http://postimg.org/image/epdsrinkx/

Is it something to worry about or should I just round down and forget about it?

Comment: You realize that you told it to print out 1000 digits of precision after the decimal point, right?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Probably a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Comment: @CrazyEddie Yes. I did it because I don't want to display large numbers in scientific notation.

Comment: @AntonSavin I'm using GNU GCC Compiler @ Code::Blocks 13.12

Comment: @vsoftco `100000` can be represented exactly, so this is not the case.

Comment: @AdamBieńkowski Which version of GCC? And what compiler flags are set? I [can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4b9f8743f6980e7)

Comment: @AntonSavin I have no flags enabled, I don't know the version but my Code::Blocks was installed last Sunday.
http://postimg.org/image/epdsrinkx/

Comment: @AntonSavin:`pow` calculates with doubles or long doubles, so `pow(10, 5)` is effectively the same as `pow(10.0, 5.0)`. you get the rounding errors in the calculation itself.

Comment: @MooingDuck but `pow(4,5)` works perfectly

Comment: Cannot reproduce using CB 13.12 + MinGW-w64 4.9.2

Comment: BTW to do the power in max precision use `pow(10.0L, length);`

Comment: Are you using compiler switch `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`? Your code is actually ill-formed in C++03 (the default mode for g++ installations) although when I tested it, older g++ versions erroneously accepted the code. Possibly your version isc alling the wrong version of `pow`.

Comment: @M.M I don't know why there is "L" letter, but result is the same. I have installed package named 'codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481.exe'

Comment: `10.0L` means the number `10` as a `long double`,  so that the version of `pow` which operates in long double precision is selected.  Try again with `-std=c++11` compiler switch. If you still get the problem then perhaps it is  a bug in TDM-GCC 4.8.1.  In any case you should update to a more recent compiler.

Comment: @M.M Unfortunately no change with that flag. What do You think about using `floor()` or multiplying with `for()` loop?

Comment: `floor` probably isn't a good idea. If your compiler allows a positive error then it might also allow a negative error in which case floor would give the wrong result.  Doing the calculation in integer precision is obviously an option, although that will be limited by the size of the integer.

Comment: @M.M I will have only positive Integers, but ints have to little space for me :( So the solution probably will be to multiple over the loop.